# How can I print the input values in between a line?

Tags: python, variables, input

```
name = input(enter name)
age = input(age)

print(“My name is print(name). I’m print(age) years old.”)
```

Nobbie experiment.
Beginner level task.
And the above query came to my mind.

Comment: First of all, you need to learn basic syntax. The prompts in `input()` need to be in quotes. And quotes have to be straight quotes, not curly quotes (turn off "Smart Quotes" in the editor when writing code.

Comment: For the answer to your main question, research string formatting in Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = input("enter name: ")
age = input("age: ")
print(f"My name is {name}. I am {age} years old")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Study and try to understand Keshav V. answer using f-strings, this is the "modern" approach and will serve you well time after after time.

A more long handed approach would be to rewrite your program like this (as a stepping stone to understanding the f-string format)..

```
name = input("enter name ")
age = input("age ")

print("My name is", name, "I’m", age, "years old.")
```

Notice that *print* will accept as many items as you want to print and place them on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use python f-strings.

```py
name = input('Enter your name ')
age = input ('Enter your age ')

print(f'My name is {name}. I\'m {age} years old.')
```

If you also want you can go with the format function.

Comment: You could also use f formatting once you have capture the input in name and age variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) formatting once you have capture the input in name and age variable.

```
print(f"My name is {name}. I'm {age} years old")
My name is laura. I'm 18 years old
```

Answer (score 0):

or this

```
name = input('Enter your name ')
age = input ('Enter your age ')
print('some text' + name + 'also some text')
```

good luck at programming,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formatted string for this:

```
def name_and_age(name, age):
    return f"My name is {name} and I'am {age} years old"
print(name_and_age('Max', 35))
#output: My name is Max and I'am 35 years old
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try string formatting.

```
name = input('Enter your name ')
age = input ('Enter your age ')

print('My name is {}. I\'m {} years old.').format(name,age)
```

[More About String Formatting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Would be a good idea to take some time to read a Python book.

```
name = input("enter name")
age = input("age")

print( f"My name is {name}. I'm {age} years old.")
```